# 500 internal server error when importing a python module in wsgi

Tags: python, apache2, cgi, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I've got a Python script that is executing functions asynchronously by using PEST wsgi library. However, when I try to import another module it simply results in a 500 error.

The way I try to reference it is:

```
from foo import * 
from foo import Foo
```

where foo is a file .py in which I have the object that I want to reference to.

Tried to monitor the calls through Chrome's Inspect Element Control but couldn't find a thing.

Also tried to debug using Apache's error log, but nothing there.
Any hints appreciated.

Update: 
I've tried the following which resulted in the same 500 error:

--make use of

```
import site
```

and

```
site.addsitedir("path/to/my/py/files/folder")
```

--modify the Apache2 httpd.conf file by inserting the following:

```
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/my/py/files/folder
```

--modify the application conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.conf, by inserting the above WSGIPythonPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/my/py/files/folder
```

before any other alias or directory in the application conf file really makes the difference.
Problem solved!

Comment: Sorry to bother, but where exactly do you add this line? Tx

Answer (score 3):

Apache's 500 error just tells you that the Python script is returning an error. My guess is that in the Apache environment, Python can't find that module.  Try a simple script that prints `sys.path` and makes sure it has the directories in it you expect.

Comment: did so and found the folder from which I'm importing the modules, but that's the same folder in which I also execute the script. I've also added a WSGIPythonPath in both the app conf and Apache's httpd.conf - the result remaining the same though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use this pattern for cgi scripts to get errors to html form:

```
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting
import traceback
# code here
except:
    tb = traceback.format_exception(sys.exc_type, sys.exc_value, sys.exc_traceback)
    tb = ''.join(tb)
    print '<pre>%s</pre></body></html>' % tb
```

Comment: They are not using CGI based on being tagged mod-wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception propagates back up to mod_wsgi then the details should be logged to appropriate Apache error log. If it isn't, then it may be that the WSGI framework/toolkit you are using is capturing the exception and returning a generic HTTP 500 response page. If that is the case, you may need to enable debug option in that WSGI framework/toolkit being used.

Alternatively, the problem isn't with the WSGI script file/application but with Apache configuration in which case you wouldn't be looking for a Python exception/traceback. You thus need to look more carefully at the Apache error log files and look for any error at all and provide what it says.

Comment: I've also checked and followed your answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2917972/228137 , but no improvement has been made unfortunately.

Comment: Instrument your code with print statements as explained in 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Apache_Error_Log_Files' and verify whether logging is working and how far things are progressing in your script. Also set 'LogLevel' directive to 'info' and look at Apache error logs to verify whether WSGI script file even being loaded.