# Apache doesn't let PIL work

Tags: php, python, json, apache, python-imaging-library

I wrote "Apache doesn't let PIL work" as title but I'm not sure about if this is the case or not.
I have a php script that sends json data to a py file that will process an image according to this json data. The communication between languages works. But when I add the line for importing PIL to py file, php returns NULL on browser. It's also working when I run the php script with command line but I have to run it on web browser.

This is the php script:

```
<?php

$result = exec('python somecode.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode('897')));
$resultData = json_decode($result, true);

var_dump($resultData);
?>
```

this is the py file:

```
import sys, json

data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print data
```

this works just fine and gives me the output of `int(897)` which is expected. When I add the line of `from PIL import Image`, it gives `NULL` on browser but it still can being ran on command line without any problem. I didn't even add the code for processing image, just trying to import PIL.

EDIT: I tried to import numpy, it didn't prevent the code from running. It runs on browser even I import numpy. So, probably problem is related with PIL.

Comment: You might have the same problem as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284362/500-internal-server-error-when-importing-a-python-module-in-wsgi

Comment: unfortunately this is not the case, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was about the image's path. I changed it to a proper one, and the problem is fixed.